# Create MySQL table with Java looks messy

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating a MySQL table in Java. I don't want to have one big string since I think it looks messy.

Is there something like this when creating a table?

```
            try (final PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + this.table + "(?, ?)")) {
            statement.setString(1, "id TINYINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL");
            statement.setString(2, "another_column TINYTEXT NOT NULL");

            statement.execute();
```

Regards

Comment: Well, It will not work since you set twice the same parameter. And this would not work since the parameter you provide would be put between quotes (I don't even think the JDBC allows DDL query in a `PreparedStatement`). You need to generate your query yourself.

Comment: Parameters are for values only, not for fragments of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create the table like this.
Use prepared statements to pass **values** to placeholders and **not** table names or column names. 
 
Change to this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + this.table + " (" + 
    "id TINYINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, another_column TINYTEXT NOT NULL)"
);
statement.execute();
```